# Getting typeError functionName function does not exist when it exists React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React.js, trying to build a todoList app. So in my component, I am creating a `<li>` element to display a to-do item that the user enters in the form. I also display a tiny delete button next to it. I basically want to delete this entry when the user clicks on the delete button. The function `removeItem()` I created in my component is the event handler for the button click. But when I call the `removeItem()` i keep getting an "typeEror, removeItem does not exist". I have tried moving it around, done binding of the `this` keyword, used an arrow function to no avail. Here's what the code looks like:

```
var TodoItems = React.createClass({

    removeItem: function() {
        alert("We are removing an Item");////////////
    },

    render: function() {
        var todoEntries = this.props.entries;

        function createTasks(item) {
    return <li key={item.key}>{item.text}<button onClick={() => this.removeItem()} className="deleteBtns">x</button></li> 
        }

        var listItems = todoEntries.map(createTasks);

        return (
            <ul className="theList">
            {listItems}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: also your map function does not look right. Change to ` todoEntries.map(item  => createTasks(item));`

Comment: Use `todoEntries.map(createTasks, this)` or make `createTasks` an arrow function. See the duplicate (same problem, slightly different error due to strict mode).

Comment: @Monica Acha, the map function is alright...the tasks are being created. My issue is with deleting tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're learning react, you should probably be using the newest version along with the [class or functional component syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) instead of `React.createClass` [which is not recommended](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-reactcreateclass).

Something like this:

```js
class TodoItems extends React.Component {
  removeItem = () => {
    alert("We are removing an Item");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="theList">
        {this.props.entries.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.key}>
            {item.text}
            <button onClick={this.removeItem} className="deleteBtns">x</button>
          </li> 
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const entries = [
  {text: 'test', key: 1},
  {text: 'test2', key: 2},
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoItems entries={entries} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```